# How do Bower, Grunt and Yeoman fit into a Visual Studio .NET workflow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, web-deployment, yeoman, bower

Tools such as Bower, Grunt and Yeoman have surged in popularity recently.

Whenever I've read about them or come across them in an article, I've dismissed them as tools used for Mac-based front-end devs or PC-based but not on the Microsoft stack - Sublime Text etc.

Visual Studio has NuGet, project templates, MSBuild, MSDeploy, TeamCity/TFS Azure etc. and I generally consider VS has being a very highly automated ecosystem (some say it makes us productive at a cost of understanding).

How are these tools being used by ASP.NET devs on VS?

Note: This is not an opinion-based question, I'm looking for real-world examples of how these tools are being used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [**Package Intellisense**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff) extension for Visual Studio which adds bower and npm package support

[image]

[**Grunt/Gulp launcher**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff) extension for launching grunt/gulp tasks

[image]

Read this awesome article written by Scott Hanselman for  more info:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx

**UPDATE:**

These features are **now fully integrated into Visual Studio 2015**:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015

Great tips from john papa:
http://www.johnpapa.net/get-up-and-running-with-node-and-visual-studio/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer and the link. I'll mark it as the answer and add my own answer with a summary of Scott's benefits in the interests of "link rot".

Answer (score 3):

As per Scott Hanselman's blog posting, he says this about the reason why a VS dev might want support for these tools:

> Some of you may ask, why not use NuGet for JavaScript? Why not extend
>   MSBuild for building CSS/JS? Simple. Because there's already a rich
>   ecosystem for this kind of thing. NuGet is great for server side
>   libraries (and some client-side) but there are so many more CSS and JS
>   libs on npm and bower. MSBuild is great for server-side builds but can
>   be overkill when building a client-side app.
>
> So, use both. These are tools in your toolkit. Adding support for
>   Gulp, Grunt, Bower, npm (and other stuff, in the future if needed)
>   means a more familiar environment for front-end devs doing ASP.NET and
>   it opens the doors for ASP.NET devs to bring in the JS and CSS
>   libraries communities use every day.

Though I'd still be interested in other people's take on how these tools fit in to the 'workflow' of a VS developer. For example, "Before I installed Grunt, I wasn't able to easily... blah."

**Update**

I'll stick some updates in here as I learn things.

- So, new learning no.1: Yeoman scaffolds front-end, client-side code. Whereas VS scaffolds server-side stuff and project templates (that don't change for months/years), Yeoman can help with boilerplate for fast-changing JS MV* frameworks, for example.
- New learning no.2: the tooling is **not ready for prime-time enterprise dev**.

The first problem is that npm downloads dependent packages into nested subfolders and recurses this model exhaustively, so you end up with folder paths that are 100s of characters long. Windows and some tooling goes nuts. There are workarounds but its a serious flaw.

> Latest Node and some added command line options now make this better behaved.

Developers running Windows are often in enterprise settings which means proxy filters and auth. For me, I needed to install Cntlm local proxy to get NPM and other tools to work via our proxy, which violates our IT policy, I just didn't tell them.

Some of NPMs packages seem to want to clone Git repos using SSH! Port 22 is not open; because the community is so Linux/Mac non-enterprise oriented, such issues arise because they're not a problem for so many creative-agency devs and then can hang around for months.

- New learning no.3: how dynamically downloaded JS files end up as content in the project file and thus added to an MS Deploy package is still an unknown.

Update on learning 3, we created a build that just transformed the config files, then we used the MSDeploy command line to copy files individually to the destination server. Not something I'd do if I were working alone, it took weeks on and off, to automate all this.

Comment: yeoman also has scaffolds for ASP.NET 5 server side templates too https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

With Bower updates are faster. Every time a new version or update is released we can easily find it in Bower. You no longer have to wait as we had to with NuGet.

So we could say that NuGet continues to be the king in the server side, but Bower is the new king of client-land.

Take a look in this post for more details and see a simple example:
http://nearsoft.com/blog/bower-and-asp-net-5-a-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question with a perspective from both enterprise and casual development...

**History**

Visual Studio has always been a standard development tool for efficiently building large-scale enterprise applications for Desktop, Mobile and Web. This included both client-side and server-side web applications built using Forms, MVC and the .NET Framework. Of course, what makes Visual Studio so appealing is the power behind it, which gives developers the ability to quickly generate, or *scaffold*, common solutions via project templates - allowing developers to focus on solving business problems.

For simple client-side web sites that use a few libraries and require minimal data interaction, a tool such as WebMatrix would often suffice due to being lightweight and able to serve up web sites with ease.

Many of those tools and technologies can be found at [Microsoft /web](https://www.microsoft.com/web/).

**Divergence**

At the same time, there has existed a burgeoning Open Source community that has been developing many of the libraries and frameworks that have risen in popularity for building modern web sites and web applications.

For developers working with the "Microsoft Stack" of technologies, the gap was originally bridged by integrating [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) into Visual Studio. Many, but not all, libraries and frameworks were available as NuGet packages; and there was plenty of support from Microsoft for working with these technologies. Microsoft had also created it's own open source mini-ecosystem called [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) to support development and sharing of projects, usually focused on their technology in some way.

Unfortunately, while the availability of technologies was fairly up to date for Microsoft developers, it had become more and more challenging to keep up because it wasn't just about the libraries and frameworks, but the workflow and the way these technologies were being made available, integrated and used.

Such workflows include:

- client-side package management via [Bower](https://bower.io/) from Twitter
  ([Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), etc.)
- node-based package management via [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)
- client-side application scaffolding via [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) (e.g. generators for [ASP.NET](https://github.com/omnisharp/generator-aspnet#readme) and [knockout](https://github.com/stevesanderson/generator-ko#readme))
- automated task running via [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

  - pre-compiling CSS from either SASS or LESS
  - transpiling languages such as ES6 or [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)
- testing ([Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html), etc.)
- bundling and deployment ([Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack), etc.)

Unfortunately, much of this is a manual process, such as identifying the right package for the job or writing different tasks that can eventually be run automatically. Each is truly a subject in and of itself! It's not uncommon to end up simply looking up a package or command for something that in the end could - and Visual Studio developers would say *should* - be automated.

**Convergence**

Microsoft has been slowly moving from not only supporting open source development but embracing it. It has made many of its core technologies available to the open source community via [GitHub](https://github.com/), as well as it's own [.NET Foundation](http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/) movement.

A major effort to converge by Microsoft was to introduce [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for multiple platforms - offering a simplified development experience that caters to the workflow that has become popular with the open source community.

Still, Visual Studio Code can be viewed as a major step back for developers used to much of the power and simplicity offered through Visual Studio through its automation of tasks and project templates. Microsoft introduced Web Essentials for [2010](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) and [2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) editions to keep up; but as many have observed, this was simply more of an effort to show support rather than a full integration into developer workflow.

Behind the scenes, Microsoft was looking to put it's .NET Framework on other platforms and established .NET Core. As of Visual Studio 2015 - specifically Update 3 and [Node Tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools) - there is much deeper support for the open source development workflow with integration of NPM and Bower, as well as task running. These still require manual intervention but it's on par with the workflow outside of Visual Studio. It still feels foreign, but it's getting there.

**The Future**

With all that Microsoft has invested, it is clear that the next step is to bring together much of the steps taken to embrace open source development by providing a more visual and automated experience to Visual Studio Developers. This will include templates that generate rich web applications which not only have all of the necessary packages and dependencies defined, but the ability to bundle for distribution.

In the meantime, I think this is a great time for Visual Studio developers to get a feel for the current workflow, if just to appreciate how "the other guys" have been doing it. It won't be long before much of it will be simply a click away.